# Create reusable chain function javascript

Tags: javascript, method-chaining, chain

I trying to create reusable chaining function, but I'm stuck. Common way `c.plus(5).plus(2).execute()` work fine, but I have no idea how to make this reusable like below. Do you have any idea how to do this?

```js
function chain() {
  this.i = 0;
  this.plus = (x) => {
    this.i = this.i + x;
    return this;
  };
  this.execute = () => console.log(this.i);
}
const c = new chain();
const c1 = c.plus(5);
c1.plus(2).execute(); // 7
c1.execute();// 7 instead of 5
```

Comment: its the same instance what do expect the result to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current function is that when you call `plus()`, you are modifying `i` in the original object `c`.

Instead, return a new `chain` object each time you call `plus(arg)`, adding `arg` to the current value of `i`.

BTW it is customary in javascript to use `TitleCase` to name constructors.  Usually `chain` would be `Chain`. FYI.

```js
function Chain() {
  this.i = 0;
  this.plus = (x) => {
    let c = new Chain();
    c.i = this.i + x;
    return c;
  };
  this.execute = () => console.log(this.i);
}
const c = new Chain();
const c1 = c.plus(5);
c1.plus(2).execute(); // 7
c1.execute();// 7 instead of 5
c.plus(2).plus(10).execute(); // 12
```

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help!